# Force Fluent migration to re-create dropped table -- Using Fluent with Vapor 3 iOS Swift MySQL

Tags: mysql, vapor, vapor-fluent

I'm using Vapor 3 for some server-side Swift, with the Fluent add-in for handling database/model management, with MySQL underneath.

I'm working in development and wanted to force the migrator to recreate a table, so I went into mysql on the command line and did:

```
mysql> drop table SomeTableName;
```

However, re-running, the migration doesn't re-create the table.  It has a zillion columns and lots of constraints, so I don't really want to do it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in the table called fluent in your database you will see a record with the name of the table. Delete this record and vapor will re-create the table the next time you run the app.

Like this:

```
mysql> drop table SomeTableName;
mysql> delete from fluent where name ='SomeTableName';
```